# Drupal 7 and Microsoft Web PI

Tags: sql-server-2008, drupal-7, sql-server-2008-r2, web-platform-installer

I am not able to proceed further while installing Drupal 7 with Microsoft Web PI. Below is image of Error

[image]

I have correctly specified the password for user "sa". The password ******** which I used to connect to SQL Server 2008 for "sa" admin, I am specifying same for Web PI. But no success.

Can anybody help me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's a windows a Security Related warning that Password should match at least 8 characters or it should be strong enough to protect from thief. So by providing proper credential error will be gone.